# Lifetime issue when mapping an iterator over elements of a matrix

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

My aim is to retrieve an iterator over all elements in a matrix alongside the row number associated with each element.

The following is a simplified version of the lifetime issue i'm running into.

```
fn main() {

    let mat = [ [1i32, 2,    3],
                [4,    5,    6],
                [7,    8,    9] ];

    // Create an iterator that produces each element alongside its row number.
    let all_elems = mat.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(row, arr)| {
        arr.iter().map(|elem| (row, elem)) // Error occurs here.
    });

    for (row, elem) in all_elems {
        println!("Row: {}, Elem: {}", row, elem);
    }

}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
<anon>:10:9: 10:43 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'r in function call due to conflicting requirements
<anon>:10         arr.iter().map(|elem| (row, elem))
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:10:24: 10:42 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 10:23...
<anon>:10         arr.iter().map(|elem| (row, elem))
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:10:24: 10:42 note: ...so type `|&i32| -> (uint, &i32)` of expression is valid during the expression
<anon>:10         arr.iter().map(|elem| (row, elem))
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:10:9: 10:43 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the method call at 10:8...
<anon>:10         arr.iter().map(|elem| (row, elem))
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:10:24: 10:42 note: ...so that argument is valid for the call
<anon>:10         arr.iter().map(|elem| (row, elem))
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here's the [playpen link](http://is.gd/Zd8QPI).

The issue seems to stem from an inability to infer the lifetime in the map method's closure argument, though I'm unsure why.

- Can someone explain the issue here a little more clearly?
- Is it possible to produce the desired iterator another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if it is not very clear, the compiler can't figure out the lifetime of your inner closure

```
|elem| (row, elem)
```

Because this closure captures `row` from its environment (here it's the body of your outer closure), thus should not be able to outlive it.

Yet, you are trying to return it wrapped into the `Map<>` object returned by `.map(..)`, and so have conflicting requirements: your inner closure is asked to outlive a scope it can't outlive !

A simple way to escape this issue is to make your inner closure take `row` as an argument as well, and to do so, we can make use of:

- `repeat(..)` which creates an iterator repeating the same item forever
- `.zip(..)` method of iterators, which allow to advance two iterators at the same time

In order to something in this way:

```
let mut all_elems = mat.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(row, arr)| {
    arr.iter()
       .zip(repeat(row))
       .map(|(elem, my_row)| (my_row, elem))
});
```

But in this case, we can make it even more simple as `|(elem, my_row)| (my_row, elem)` looks pretty useless:

```
let mut all_elems = mat.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(row, arr)| {
    repeat(row).zip(arr.iter())
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to increase the lifetime of the inner closure `|elem| (row, elem)`
would be to mark it as a moving closure by simply adding the `move` keyword. This will also compile:

```
let all_elems = mat.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(row, arr)| {
    arr.iter().map(move |elem| (row, elem))
});
```

The same behavior can also be observed when trying to return a (boxed) closure from a function. The following function fails to compile because the lifetime of the closure is bound by the lifetime of the local variable `row`:

```
fn foo_fail() -> Box<Fn(u32) -> (u32, u32)> {
    let row = 1;
    Box::new(|elem| (row, elem))
}
```

Using a moving closure instead will work fine:

```
fn foo_success() -> Box<Fn(u32) -> (u32, u32)> {
    let row = 1;
    Box::new(move |elem| (row, elem))
}
```